# Seemingly magical behaviour in my Clojure REPL

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I’m tinkering with Clojure, and currently experimenting with the `clojure.lang.PersistentQueue` to model the waiting room in Dijkstra’s *Sleeping Barber* problem.

```
barber.core=> (def q (ref clojure.lang.PersistentQueue))
#'barber.core/q
barber.core=> q
#<Ref@37c3a6f0: clojure.lang.PersistentQueue>
barber.core=> @q
clojure.lang.PersistentQueue
barber.core=> (dosync (alter q concat :customer))

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Class  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
barber.core=> (dosync (alter q conj :customer))

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
barber.core=> (dosync (alter q conj :customer))
(:customer)
```

As you can see, I send the same command twice. On the first time it throws an exception. The second time however, seems to work just fine. I can now `conj` and `pop` my `q` until Hickey’s cows come home.

In what world is this acceptable? What is happening behind the scenes that I’m not seeing?

[image: Whatever is going on here, I don’t like it.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`PersistentQueue` is a class, not an instance of that class. Use `PersistentQueue/EMPTY` instead.

Secondly, `concat` returns a lazy sequence, regardless of the type you passed in. You can't `concat` on a queue and get a queue back. Use `conj`, which is polymorphic, instead.

A lot of this is undefined behavior. Garbage in, garbage out.

What I think is happening is an interaction of laziness and errors. When you try to `concat` on the `PersistentQueue` class, it **successfully** returns a lazy sequence. The error happens outside the transaction when you try to print the value. Printing caused the evaluation of the **first** element of the sequence (the `PersistentQueue` class), but `concat` is lazy: it has not yet tried to make a sequence of the **second** argument (`:customer`). Your Ref now contains a lazy sequence whose **second** element has not yet been evaluated.

The second time you try to modify the Ref, `conj` forced the evaluation of next available element of the lazy sequence in the Ref, yielding another error. Since the sequence failed to produce any values, its value is an **empty** lazy sequence.

Now your Ref contains an empty sequence, for which `conj` is defined to call `cons`. Now your Ref contains a non-lazy sequence of one element, effectively a list.

Comment: This language is voodoo.

Comment: The second error is from the original `concat` call (the second is a `conj`). Is the ref somehow caching each exception until it gets cleared out?

Comment: Hmm, I see... `concat` wraps both bad conversions (class-to-seq and keyword-to-seq) in thunks, and it takes two attempts to realize the lazy seq to force them.

Comment: @JezenThomas You don't really need to understand the details of what Stuart is saying here: it sounds like voodoo because he's explaining the implementation details of what actually happens when you do something illegal, which is all rather abstruse. But if you just follow the advice of his first sentence you will avoid getting into weird error scenarios; your Clojure programs won't have to care about voodoo.